# Bayesian Statistics with simple data set, 1 model

Tags: python, bayesian, pymc3

I'm fairly new to python and Bayesian statistics. Most of the intro examples on the web work through switchpoints or multiple parameters. For my data, I just wanted to plot the 95% HPD and determine the mean. I wanted to compare frequentest versus Bayesian statistics with simple data and simple models.

I guess my question is, did I model this correctly?

### Plotting data in histrogram

```
import pandas as pd
import pymc3 as pm

data = np.array([0.170717, 0.174359, 0.172085, 0.171650, 0.171511, 0.175207,
                         0.174769, 0.174633, 0.174814, 0.174655, 0.199607,     0.198277,
                         0.199973, 0.142929, 0.143697, 0.143240, 0.143503, 0.144641,
                         0.143488, 0.145386, 0.143688, 0.144603, 0.144529, 0.191608,
                         0.192063, 0.192355, 0.193154, 0.156040, 0.158525, 0.155890,
                         0.156021, 0.155429, 0.157540, 0.156556, 0.158478, 0.161370,
                         0.161220, 0.167436, 0.161289, 0.162017, 0.167989, 0.170717,
                         0.174359, 0.172085, 0.171650, 0.171511, 0.175207])

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.plot(kind='hist')
plt.title("Histogram")
plt.xlabel("Value")
[histogram][1]

## Modeling the prior as Normal Distribution

with pm.Model():
    mu = pm.Normal('mu', 0, 1) #prior 
    sigma = .01

    returns = pm.Normal('returns', mu=mu, sd=sigma, observed=data) #likelihood 

    step = pm.NUTS()
    trace = pm.sample(10000, step, tune=500)
## Plotting trace
pm.traceplot(trace)
pm.summary(trace)

pm.plots.plot_posterior(trace)
[posterior][3]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZTgfy.png
  [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LEKem.png
```

Comment: what happens when you run the code? What's your expected output, and how does it compare?

Comment: It returns code that makes sense. I couldn't post pics, but there's links at the end of the original post. I guess looking at it now, I lucked out by picking a Normal dist for the prior. Without any knowledge I probably should have picked a student t or uniform dist. I just tried a uniform dist for the prior, and that post looks like garbage.